# Amazon Simple Email Service is not working on port 465

Tags: amazon-simple-email-service

I'm trying to make sending email work using Amazon Simple Email Service SMTP.

I configured the email sending to use port 465 with SSL as the CDOSys available for VB Script does not support TLS. But even so I get the error error '80040211' on the line where the objCDOSYSMail.Send command is located

I tested the connection to port 465 through TELNET and everything indicates that there is no problem connecting to the port.

Below is my test code, I censored only my smtp login and password.
I'm grateful for any help you can offer me. I also tested with ports 25 and 587

```
Set objCDOSYSMail = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set objCDOSYSCon = Server.CreateObject ("CDO.Configuration")


'SERVIDOR DE SMTP 
objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "email-smtp.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com"
 
'PORTA PARA COMUNICAÇÃO COM O SERVIÇO DE SMTP 
objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 465
 
'PORTA DO CDO 
objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2 
 
'Utilização de SSl 
objCDOSYSCon.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = true
 
'ATIVAR RECURSO DE SMTP AUTENTICADO 
objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = true 
 

'USUARIO PARA SMTP AUTENTICADO 
objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
 
'SENHA DO USUARIO PARA SMTP AUTENTICADO 
objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
 
'TEMPO DE TIMEOUT (EM SEGUNDOS) 
objCDOSYSCon.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 30


objCDOSYSCon.Fields.update
Set objCDOSYSMail.Configuration = objCDOSYSCon
objCDOSYSMail.From = "loja@sabarabucu.com"
objCDOSYSMail.To = "ronaldo@onemedia.com.br"
objCDOSYSMail.Subject = "Teste"
objCDOSYSMail.HtmlBody = "Testando"
objCDOSYSMail.Send
Set objCDOSYSMail = nothing
Set objCDOSYSCon = nothing
```